# How to make Datatable Jquery dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I need to make a table dynamically with **DataTable Jquery**, the table must be ***Server-side processing*** type and in the same request (Ajax) and answer the columns are made and obviously the results.

```
DatosColumna=""//Json with Response of ajax

$('#table_query_info').dataTable({
    columnDefs: DatosColumna,//Here its the headers
    destroy: true,
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
        url: myBaseUrl + "consults/find_docs",
        type: "post",
        data: function (d) {
            d.datos = make_info()//Send Json with info
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function (resp) {
                alert("OK");//That Good
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I tried with this code but it has not worked

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a *specific* programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: jQuery runs client side. What PHP script are you using to try and make the table?

Comment: I Use PHP but this not my problem, in my Json return the head and the rows, but i don't knows the correkly form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

steps for resolution:

1. make a html code

`<table class="table" id="tablaindex" style="width:100%"></table>`

1. Obtengo las columnas, antes de inicializar la tabla

   `$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "AtencionTurno/ColumnasDatatable",
       data: TblOficina,
       success: function (response) {
           inicializarTabla(response);
       }, error: function (request, status, error) {
           console.log("Error");
       }
   });`
2. The reques obtain the follow json

   `[
   {
       "title": "Column 1",
       "data": "Id_Turno",
       "orderable": false
   },
   {
       "title": "Column 2",
       "data": "Turno",
       "orderable": false
   },
   {
       "title": "Column 3",
       "data": "Clasificacion",
       "orderable": false
   },
   {
       "title": "Column 4",
       "data": "Concepto",
       "orderable": false
   },
   {
       "title": "Column 5",
       "data": "Hora",
       "orderable": false
   }]`
3. now I initialize the table with the columns that were obtained

   `inicializarTabla = function (columnas) {
   var dataTable = $('#tablaindex').DataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   stateSave: true,
   orderable: false,
   "order": [],
   columns: columnas,
   "lengthChange": false,
   searching: false,
   colReorder: false,
   "ajax": {
       url: "AtencionTurno/IndexTurnos",
       type: "post",
       data: TblOficina
   }
   });
   };`
4. response from server:

   `{
   "draw": "1",
   "recordsTotal": 4,
   "recordsFiltered": 4,
   "data": [
       {
           "Id_Turno": "358",
           "Turno": "ALAT1",
           "Clasificacion": "euismod",
           "Concepto": "Convallis",
           "Hora": "11:00:12",
           "Tiempo_Espera": "2018/07/03 11:00:12",
           "Tipo_Cliente": "Calendario",
           "Transferencia": "",
           "null": "358"
       },
       {
           "Id_Turno": "354",
           "Turno": "ALAK23",
           "Clasificacion": "euismod",
           "Concepto": "Pagos",
           "Hora": "16:36:14",
           "Tiempo_Espera": "2018/06/29 16:36:14",
           "Tipo_Cliente": "Utiles Escolares ",
           "Transferencia": "",
           "null": "354"
       }
   ]
   }`